# iptables failed to forward packages to NFQ

Tags: iptables

I have set the following rules in iptables:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.37.184 -j NFQUEUE
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j NFQUEUE
```

What I want to do is forward all Mysql traffic data to NFQ, and I wish to detect these data in Suricata, but these iptable rules not working as expected, *only part of the data* in NFQ goes into Suricata(or only part of data goes into NFQ). but when I set the following iptables:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE
```

This works well, all the packages go into NFQ and all detected by Suricata, but this iptable rule forward all the traffic onto NFQ, and this is not I want.

My question is how to set specific iptables rules **only** apply to Mysql protocol?

Comment: Are you running Suricata on the MySQL client or on the server?  See https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Setting_up_IPSinline_for_Linux

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the NFQ kernel module loaded:

```
lsmod | grep nfnetlink_queue
```

Check to see if packets are matching those iptables rules

```
sudo iptables -vn -L
```

To just use the Suricata target for MySQL, the following should work:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j NFQUEUE
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -j NFQUEUE
```